# How to insert newline into MS Teams markdown?

Tags: markdown, microsoft-teams

When I enter markdown format in MS Teams (```), how do I create a newline in a string? When a human types in markdown format, pressing Enter results in a newline. When I send a string with `<br>`, `\n` or `\r\n` in text to the connector, it does not create a newline.  I've found that I can escape markdown, enter a `<br>`, and enter markdown again, but then it reformats each line to remove whitespace.

So how can I create a newline and maintain my spacing?

If this matters, I'm using pymsteams connector.

Edit: adding code example

````
import pymsteams
msg = pymsteams.connectorcard('...')
txt = '``` some text \n second line ```'
msg.text(txt)
msg.send()
````

I've also tried ```` txt = '``` some text \r\n second line ```' ```` and ```` txt = '``` some text <br> second line ```' ````, but none of the 3 options insert a newline between "some text" and "second line".

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you're trying to just send a connector card w/ text in markdown, there's no need to enclose the text in triple backticks (unless you specifically want preformatted text). We automatically treat the text in a connector card as markdown, unless you set the `markdown` property to false.

To add line break in markdown, end the line with 3 spaces + linebreak. For example:

```
msg.text("Line 1   \nLine 2")
```

**Connector cards sent by a bot:**

If you added those triple backticks to get preformatted text, then you need to place the backticks on their own lines to allow multiline text. For example:

````
msg.text("```\nLine 1\nLine 2\n```")
````

**Connector cards sent by a Connector:**

If you're developing a connector or using the incoming webhook connector, that uses a different parser that doesn't convert "```" markdown to a `<pre>` tag. It's best to just fall back to HTML, as Bill suggested below. For example:

```
msg.text("<pre>Line 1\nLine 2</pre>")
```

HTML tags work inside a `<pre>` element, so as you found out, this is equivalent:

```
msg.text("<pre>Line 1<br>Line 2</pre>")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is this true if I post to an incoming webhook? I just tested your examples via webhook, and I don't find that I'm formatted in markdown automatically or that the backticks on their own lines allowed me to give a newline between them :(

Comment: Oh, good question! I assumed this was a bot posting a connector card to a conversation. Incoming webhooks go through a different path, so it could behave differently too. In that case it might be easier to use simple HTML tags, e.g. `br` for simple line break, and `pre` for preformatted text. The built-in connectors (e.g., Bing News, Twitter) use simple HTML tags.

Comment: This worked! Thanks. You can make it your answer and I'll accept it. `<pre> line 1 <br> line 2 </pre>`

Comment: Terrific! I edited my answer to note the difference between cards sent by bots and connectors.

Comment: Using `<pre>Code</pre>` solved my problem but anyone knows the problem with underscores??

Answer (score 6):

You didn't provide any code, so it's hard to say exactly what you're trying, but if I set the `text` value in the card to this:

```
"text": "text": "There is a problem with Push notifications.<br><br>They don't seem to be picked up by the connector."
```

This how it's rendered:

[image]

Comment: And because they didn't provide any code, the question is off topic and you should be voting to close it, not answer it. [Should one advise on off topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)

Comment: I was trying to work in markdown (string enclosed by triple backticks ```)

Comment: This is a very relevant question regardless of it including code or not.