# Adding CR LF to a Teams chat message programmatically

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-api

I have an application that sends chat message like so:

```
const currentUserId: any = await msGraphProvider.getCurrentUserId();
const userIdToSendMessage: any = await msGraphProvider.getUserId(dpcRequest.SendQuestionsTo.EMail);
const chatOfUser: any = await msGraphProvider.createUsersChat(userIdToSendMessage, currentUserId);
const result: any = await msGraphProvider.sendMessage(chatOfUser, text);
```

the text variable should have few new lines in it but anything I send is disregarded.
I tried 
 but it is not HTML
also \r\n\r\n , \n but it is ignored too

Any Idea how to format new lines?
Thanks

Comment: Can you please share the Graph API documentation link that you are following, so that I can further check on the issue ? Are you using C# Graph SDK or another one?

Answer (score 0):

A simple text message like this (as opposed to, say, an Adaptive Card message) actually uses markdown, just fyi - you can see more at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-markdown-formatting-in-teams-4d10bd65-55e2-4b2d-a1f3-2bebdcd2c772

That doesn't help you though, it's just fyi. For newline, this might be relevant: [How to insert newline into MS Teams markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52637567/how-to-insert-newline-into-ms-teams-markdown)